# Easy way python async method wanted

Tags: python, python-asyncio, nest-asyncio

I am developing a small media player app on raspberry pi. So This have two main functions. Namely radio and file player. If entered into file player below is the code :

```
        
        process = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer',songs[0],'-o','local'],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
        #stdout = process.communicate()[0]
        
        nxt=0
        while True:
            print("looping")
            output = process.stdout.readline()
            if nxt>1:     
                process = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', songs[nxt],'-o','local'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                output = process.stdout.readline()
                #stdout = process.communicate()[0]
                
            if output =='' :
                print("2")
            if output:
                print("finshed")
                nxt=nxt+1
            if GPIO.input(7)==0:
                break
```

The problem is code after and outside this loop doesnt work before the subprocess is finished. How can I use ayncio so that some gpio readings can be taken and exit this loop once needed ? I really spent 8 hours to figureout this googling this. But all available tutorials are very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interacting with a live process, you need to have some handle to do so - often this will look like a [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html), which seems to be what the process expects from these examples (briefly skimmed)

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=28614
- https://github.com/stifi/Python-omxplayer-Socket

However, in order for your Python process to also do some logic while managing this, you'll need one of the following

- [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html): likely easier to reason about, but with more troublesome caveats (limited maximum interactions, cleanup, serializing commands..)
- [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html): likely the best choice overall, but potentially more troublesome to reason about at first
- [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html): similar to threading, but perhaps the most troublesome to reason about (ie. how do the processes communicate?) and least beneficial for your case (simply writing or reading a socket)

---

It's beyond the scope of the question, but to get started, you may find it easy to

- write a small test script for interacting with sockets to learn how they work
- play with with a good, but simple async web framework like [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) to understand how asynchronous logic behaves
- combine 'em using [with Tornado's IOStream logic](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/iostream.html#tornado.iostream.IOStream) to make a complete example
- continue with your new design ideas